# DIV resizing in JS : can this be done before the page is displayed?

Tags: php, javascript

In my page I give a certain size to a DIV with jQuery, based on the size of the last tweet that I retrieve through PHP.

Problem : I need to use jQuery(window).bind("load", function() in order for jQuery to "see" the size of the tweet, but then, I can see the resizing (perfomed my jQuery) in front of my eyes and I dislike it. I want the page to appear in its final state.

Is that possible ?

Comment: How about hiding the tweet and fading it in once the resize has been done? Alternatively, instead of binding it to the window load, bind it to document ready, or execute it right after the element is added to the dom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. 1) Start off with your tweet element hidden, then show/fade it in when everything is loaded.

2) My preferred solution is to call the [$.blockUI()](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) plugin as soon possible, and then $.unblockUI when everything has loaded. The blockUI plugin also has a facility for blocking only certain elements rather than the whole page, there is a demo [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element)

Answer (score 0):

You can always let it render at a top margin of -1000px and then pop it back down, or perhaps z-index it underneath something else.
Some browsers have problems "seeing" hidden divs while some can do it, but it's unrelible so best bet is to render it outside the canvas.